# Background image in login showing in admin area

Tags: admin, customization

I have customized my login screen with a logo using html{background:#E2DEAF url(.../images/login_logo.jpg) center top no-repeat;} because it is so wide. Usually would not tie something to the HTML element. works great BUT... it also shows up in the admin area. Anyway to prevent this? I only want it on the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting login body class instead of adding background to html tag.

```
body.login {
   background:#E2DEAF url(.../images/login_logo.jpg);
}
```

You could also play with .page (pages only), .logged-in (logged users) and so forth :)

Hope it helps.